# What am I doing wrong in this pandas dataframe drop operation to result in a KeyError?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When running this line of code:

```
df = df.drop(df[(len(df.Sentences) > 40)].index)
```

It returns:

```
KeyError: True
```

I was expecting it to remove all rows with Sentence length of more than 40 characters.

Hopefully there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break down your statement:

1. `len(df.Sentences)` returns the number of elements you have in the Sentences column.  You can verify that but just looking at the result of this statement.
2. Most likely you have more than 40 elements, so `len(df.Sentences)>40` returns True which you then use as the index [] which returns the key error.

So the problem is getting the lengths of the individual elements.  Let's try `df.Sentences.str.len()` which should do the trick.

Here is a complete sample:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['aaa',1,2,3], ['bbbbb',4,5,6],['ccc',7,8,9]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
>>> df
       A  B  C  D
0    aaa  1  2  3
1  bbbbb  4  5  6
2    ccc  7  8  9
>>> df.drop(df[df.A.str.len()>4].index)
     A  B  C  D
0  aaa  1  2  3
2  ccc  7  8  9
```